# How to remove the delay in loading images from server when using glide?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have an activity with recyclerView inside it, i want to load images from server and showing them in recyclerView using glide library.

Images have different size (600x400, 900x1360, ...).

Problem: when scrolling fast to bottom or top, there is a delay in loading and showing images:

[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlrUU.gif)

what can i do to remove this annoying delay?

Activity xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/act_main_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

recyclerView items xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:text="Image Name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/postImage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

onBindViewHolder in recyclerView adapter:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Image_ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(addresses.get(position))
                .into(holder.postImage);

    }
```

ps. if i set a fix size for imageView (eg. 600 x 400) the problem will be solved, but i want image in original size.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your Glide code with this :

```
Glide.with(context).load(addresses.get(position))
                    .override(nWidth, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)                       
                    .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
                    .into(holder.imgLogo);
```

nWidth = Resize your image in perticular px. (Ex. 200)

And one more suggestion for your issue if you can able to receive an image size then apply that dimension as an ImageView heigh & width.

Comment: What is **Constant.nWidth** ?